# How to get ASTNode definition in JDT?

Tags: eclipse-jdt

I can get IBinding from a MethodInvocation.getName() and now I want to get the offset of this binding in the CompilationUnit in order to get the definition position. But I can not find any information of this. By the way, I use ASTParser.setSource(char[]) not IJavaProject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal approach in JDT looks like this:

```
IJavaElement method= methodBinding.getJavaElement();
if (method instanceof IMember) {
    ICompilationUnit cu= ((IMember) method).getCompilationUnit();
    CompilationUnit compilationUnit= // use ASTParser here...
    ASTNode methodDecl= compilationUnit.findDeclaringNode(methodBinding.getKey());
    ... methodDecl.getStartPosition() ...
}
```

This, however, requires that the Java Model is available. If you don't have an `IJavaProject` then `#getJavaElement()` will probably answer `null`. In that case you will have to implement your own heuristic for mapping an `ITypeBinding` (from `IMethodBinding#getDeclaringClass()`) to a compilation unit.

Put differently: if you want JDT to help locating elements outside the current compilation unit, then using the Java Model is the way to go.

As an alternative to using the full-blown Java Model, you could try parsing all relevant compilation units in one batch (using `#getASTs()` - plural), and then create your own reverse map from `ITypeBinding` to `CompilationUnit`.

Comment: At first, I want to finish a small static code analysis demo using JDT.  Put some target java files as input, parse them and then use my own visitors to check the code. So that's why I need `ASTNode` line information and `ASTNode` definition postion. It will be easier if I use Java Model to do that just as you say. So I need convert outside java project path to a Eclipse java project? Can you show me a little tips about that? Thanks a lot. @Stephan Hermann